# Does ARC manage memory for CGPDF types?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, quartz-2d

I'm working on a custom PDF library for iOS and noticed that there are explicit functions for retaining and releasing `CGPDFDocumentRefs` `andPageRefs`. Does ARC handle the retain/release of such opaque types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. ARC does not currently handle the memory management for anything except Obj-C objects (which CGPDF things aren't).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I recently converted to ARC in PSPDFKit 1.8. After considering a lot of tricks, like bringing ARC to autorelease an item, or using associated values, I finally use a container class that manages the references on the CoreFoundation-Level.

It's tricky, as if you have a CGPDFPage and you release the CGPDFDocument, further calls to the CGPDFPage will crash, even if that one's retained. So be careful with the references.

Related, it's not a good idea to keep many CGPDFDocumentRefs open - they may need A LOT of memory, malloc's of 15MB are not unusual. So in my library I took great care that things get released fast when there's a memory warning.